# how to change login page phpfox, i want to add an block to the left or the right column?

Tags: block, phpfox, login-page

I want to change the structure of page to 2 columns,
for example I want to add a left column for Login page instead of a 1 column  (add block3)
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you using

For 4 version , You make change in core file and make change in structure by adding block

Adding block and customization in blocks position
phpfox\PF.Src\Core\View.php

```
$params['footer'] = new View\Functions('footer');
        $params['errors'] = new View\Functions('errors');
        $params['top'] = new View\Functions('top');
        $params['left'] = new View\Functions('left');
        $params['right'] = new View\Functions('right');
        /*custom*/$params['rs_left'] = new View\Functions('rs_left');
        /*custom*/$params['rs_mid_top'] = new View\Functions('rs_mid_top');
        $params['h1'] = new View\Functions('h1');
        $params['breadcrumb'] = new View\Functions('breadcrumb');
        $params['notification'] = new View\Functions('notification');
```

phpfox\PF.Src\Core\View\ Functions.php

```
/*custom*/case 'rs_left':
                    $this->_loadBlocks(9);
                    break;  
                /*custom*/case 'rs_mid_top':
                    $this->_loadBlocks(12);
                    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not add block directly from admin at login page becuase this controller not defined in Admincp if you want to add any html you can write html in login template file